# How can I set a background picture on my window in Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the code setting the Background:

```
'''
Background picture:

'''
background_image=tk.PhotoImage("blood_PNG6140.png")
background_label = tk.Label(parent, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

I am getting this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lana/Desktop/Zaid/End_Projekt_MakE_YouR_ChoicE_zaid_zaim ON MAC/MakeYourChoice.py", line 275, in <module>
    background_image=tk.PhotoImage("blood_PNG6140.png")
NameError: name 'tk' is not defined
>>>
```

Thank you in advance!
ZZaim

Comment: you need to import tkinter as tk.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import `tkinter`. Place

```
import tkinter as tk
```

in the header of your .py file.

Comment: The another Error is:
line 277, in <module>
    background_label = tk.Label(parent, image=background_image)
NameError: name 'parent' is not defined
>>>

Comment: line 276, in <module>
    parent = tkinter.tk()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tk'

Answer (score 0):

Add `import tkinter as tk` to the top of your code